# Does php7 still support global variables?

Tags: php, global-variables

It is possible to use global variable within function in **php7**? It worked properly in php5.4.

I have found that keyword **global** is not usefull any more in php7:

> global only accepts simple variables [migration70.incompatible](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php)

But There on page about GLOBALS [reserved.variables.globals](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) 
it is still written that (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7) should support GLOBALS.

Unfortunatelly, nothing of these work for me:

```
function printGlobal(){
  global ${$a};
  global $b;
  echo '<br/>-'.${$a};
  echo '<br/>-'.$b;
  echo '<br/>-'.$GLOBALS['c'];
}

$a = "hello";
$b = 7;
$c = 6;

printGlobal();
```

output:

```
-
-
-
```

Please do not start a discussion about avoiding of usage of global variables :)

--- EDIT:

I missed, that X.php file I worked with is included withinin index.php file in a function includeAnotherPage(..). Thus, variable defined in X.php file cannot be global variable - because whole X.php file is already in a function. Therefore, codes, writen above, did not work.

Ok thank you for replies. I am stupid and the article locked me in the feeling that globals could be deactivated.

Comment: What php version do you use? The first one of course won't work, but the other ones should work fine: https://3v4l.org/Zj5LF#v510

Comment: Your output is incorrect. it is `- -7 -6`

Comment: Does work, but `$a` is undefined in the function as long as you don't put `global $a;` before using it.

Comment: As @CharlotteDunois mentioned, you need to define all global variables before you define function where you call your variables, so $a, $b, $c go above printGlobal()

Comment: No. The exact code printed above gives the output `- -7 -6` no need to change anything. PHP ver. 7.0.10

Comment: Shouldn't you declare the variable as a global variable before assigning it a value or using it in a function? So at the top of the page just do "global $a;" before u do "$a=6;"

Comment: What no longer works is using global with *variable variables*. But almost any use of variable variables indicates poor design to begin with, you should use an associative array instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHP also gives you the option of defining Global Variables using one of the Super-Globals: `$GLOBALS`. So you could do something like below which you might [QUICK TEST Here](https://eval.in/700117) as well:

```
<?php

    $GLOBALS['a']      = "hello";
    $GLOBALS['b']      = 7;
    $GLOBALS['c']      = 6;
    $GLOBALS['hello']  = "Howdy...";

    function printGlobal(){
      $a = $GLOBALS['a'];
      $b = $GLOBALS['b'];
      $c = $GLOBALS['c'];
      $d = $GLOBALS[$a];

      echo '<br/>-'.$d;
      echo '<br/>-'.$b;
      echo '<br/>-'.$c;
    }

    printGlobal();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost good, but you have a syntax problem. This code is almost same as your, but it works (tested with PHP 7.0.12).

```
<?php
function printGlobal() {
    global $a;
    global $b;
  echo '<br />-'.$a; //Echoes $a
  echo '<br />-'.$b; //Echoes $b
  echo '<br />-'.$GLOBALS['c']; //Echoes $c from from the array $GLOBALS
}

$a = 1;
$b = 2;
$c = 3;

printGlobal();
```

As you can see, in `printGlobal` I just specify I'm using $a and $b as global, and in the echo, I use $a instead of ${a}, because ${a} can be used inside a double quoted string, here you are outside any quote.

See [$GLOBALS](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php), that says there is no need to use `global $variable` because $GLOBALS is available everywhere.

Output:

```
<br/>-1<br/>-2<br />-3
```

Note that you should use \n to write on a new line.

**EDIT:** Note that in an anonymous function, the `use`keywork is available so you can use it to bring variables in the scope of the function.

```
<?php
$message = "Hello world!";
$ex = function() use ($message) {
    echo $message;
}
```

See [use keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

Comment: It should print "3" as well, right?  <br/>-1<br/>-2<br/>-3

Comment: Yes it prints "3" as well, I've updates my answer. Thanks.

Comment: You're right @FrankForte, I've update my answer. Thanks.