# Yii2: Global variable in view

Tags: php, global

I'm need to concatenate lines for later output (markdown processing...). This is why I use a function `l()` and a global variable `$content`.

My view code:

```
$content = "";
function l($line="") {
    global $content;
    $content .= $line."\n";
}
l("hello");
echo "+";
echo $content;
echo "-";
```

outputs

```
+-
```

I'd expect:

```
+Hello-
```

Why? What am I doing wrong?

I am using PHP 7.2.6

EDIT:

There are several PHP related answers as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127788/changing-a-global-variable-from-inside-a-function-php). But they don't help. I suppose the problem is related to Yii2 and more specific to Yii2 view handling.

Comment: shouldnt you return `$content` and do `echo l("hello")` ? or just `echo $content` in the function

Comment: sorry, I corrected the code sample.

Comment: i think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41210784/does-php7-still-support-global-variables) would address your problem as for me in php `5.6` it works correctly

Comment: not really. Maybe using the supergobal ```$GLOBAL``` could help. But I want to know whats going on here in PHP. Why does the global keyword not help to access ```$content``` in exactely my piece of code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing a global variable from inside a function PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127788/changing-a-global-variable-from-inside-a-function-php)

Comment: I suggest you another solution instead of using global variables, just use \yii\base\View::$params. Here is examples  https://stackoverflow.com/a/28039305/3041129

Comment: That could be another solution, indeed. But why is my code not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution! Crazy!

Yii2 renders the view [inside an object instance](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/62c8a59e7bc5faf5942ab843f070b1c66c51db97/framework/base/View.php#L348).

This means, the PHP variable declaration

```
$content = "";
```

is not global but local to the [rendering context](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/62c8a59e7bc5faf5942ab843f070b1c66c51db97/framework/base/View.php#L348).

The solution for question is to make the variable declaration in the view global, too:

```
global $content = "";
```

The working code inside the view looks like this now:

```
global $content = "";
function l($line="") {
    global $content;
    $content .= $line."\n";
}
l("hello");
echo "+";
echo $content;
echo "-";
```

Bingo!